# Vlookup Scripting Dictionary

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have the following code for a Vlookup in VBA.  The code works for the most part, but I am getting blanks for cells that should have values (When I run the actual Vlookup in Excel formula, it returns a value).  Does anyone know where I could be going wrong here?

```
Sub TestVBA()
    OptimizeVBA True
    Dim startTime As Single, endTime As Single
    startTime = Timer

    Dim FISTrim As Range, ProfileName As Range
    Dim lookupFISTrim As Range, lookupProfileName As Range
    Dim vlookupCol As Object

    Set FISTrim = Worksheets("PF-Outstandings 02-22 02-23").Range("C2:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    Set ProfileName = Worksheets("PF-Outstandings 02-22 02-23").Range("D2:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    Set lookupFISTrim = Worksheets("FISV 02-23").Range("C4:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    Set lookupProfileName = Worksheets("FISV 02-23").Range("D4:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

    'Build Collection
    Set vlookupCol = BuildLookupCollection(FISTrim, ProfileName)

    'Lookup the values
    VLookupValues lookupFISTrim, lookupProfileName, vlookupCol
    endTime = Timer
    Debug.Print (endTime - startTime) & " seconds have passed [VBA]"
    OptimizeVBA False
    Set vlookupCol = Nothing
End Sub

Function BuildLookupCollection(categories As Range, values As Range)
    Dim vlookupCol As Object, i As Long
    Set vlookupCol = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = 1 To categories.Rows.Count
        vlookupCol.Item(CStr(categories(i))) = values(i)
    Next i

    Set BuildLookupCollection = vlookupCol
End Function

Sub VLookupValues(lookupCategory As Range, lookupValues As Range, vlookupCol As Object)
    Dim i As Long, resArr() As Variant
    ReDim resArr(lookupCategory.Rows.Count, 1)
    For i = 1 To lookupCategory.Rows.Count
        resArr(i - 1, 0) = vlookupCol.Item(CStr(lookupCategory(i)))
    Next i
    lookupValues = resArr
End Sub

Sub OptimizeVBA(isOn As Boolean)
    Application.Calculation = IIf(isOn, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
    Application.EnableEvents = Not (isOn)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = Not (isOn)
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = Not (isOn)
End Sub
```

Comment: The code `Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` returns the last row of the current sheet. You need to refer to the targeted sheet with `Worksheets(...).Cells(...)` or `With Worksheets(...)` then `.Cells(...)`.

Comment: to give some additional detail, I am performing a Vlookup in Column D of tab "FISV 02-23" with reference of Columns C&D in tab "PF Oustandings 02-22 02-23" ... there are 250K plus rows in this - some are not returning values when they should be

Comment: The code Cells(Row.Count, "A"....) is just giving me my range of the last row that there is a value in Column A

Comment: @ZacharyDesgain - read again the first comment.

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you mean by that..

Comment: Your segment `Cells(Row.Count,"A")` is referring to whatever happens to be the active sheet at the time, which will not be the desired sheet.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the most common error in VBA, that everyone has made at least once. It is a great idea to always refer to the parent worksheet, when you are referring to ranges. Thus:

```
'instead of:
Set FISTrim = Worksheets("PF-Outstandings 02-22 02-23").Range("C2:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

'try this:
With Worksheets("PF-Outstandings 02-22 02-23")
    Set FISTrim = .Range("C2:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
End With
```

Make sure that you set all the ranges in your code this way.

What is the difference? In the first case the `.Cells` refers to the `ActiveSheet` and in the second case it refers to the "PF-Outstandings...".

Comment: So would I need to do this with each of the 4 rows I have that begin with Set?

Comment: @ZacharyDesgain - **Yes**.  Or leave it as it is and use the ugly `Worksheets("PF-Outstandings 02-22 02-23").Select`  before each of them.

Comment: and I am guessing I need to put End With after each one as well?

Comment: With the changes made above, my macro now returns incorrect matches and also leaves a significant amount blank...?

Comment: @ZacharyDesgain - then start debugging with F8 to see where the problem is. Make some really small example of your data, up to 3-4 lines and it will not be very time consuming.

Comment: There is no error when running the script though.  It executes fine, but it just gives me values that are not correct, and leaves a lot blank... more so than when the code was what I had